# Boolean constructor returns odd data

Tags: javascript

Why is it in javascript after calling `a=new Boolean()`

- `a==false` returns true
- `Boolean(a)` returns true
- `if (a) {}`  is ran

Shouldn't they all be the same?

Comment: Because `typeof a == object`

Comment: `new Boolean()` returns an object, `Boolean()` returns a primitive value.

Answer (score 1):

The new keyword returns a Boolean object, which is not exactly the same as false.

```
var a = new Boolean();

// a is a Boolean object
typeof a === 'object';

// using equality operator, a appears to be false
a == false;

// using identity, a is not actually false
a !== false;

// casting your Boolean object results in true,
// similar to casting any other object
Boolean(a) === true;
Boolean({}) === true;
```

Check out the [description from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Boolean).  You'll see that passing an object to Boolean, creates an object with the value *true*.

> The value passed as the first parameter is converted to a boolean value, if necessary. If value is omitted or is 0, -0, null, false, NaN, undefined, or the empty string (""), the object has an initial value of false. All other values, **including any object** or the string "false", **create an object with an initial value of true**.

Answer (score 0):

> The value passed as the first parameter is converted to a boolean
>   value, if necessary. If value is omitted or is 0, -0, null, false,
>   NaN, undefined, or the empty string (""), the object has an initial
>   value of false. All other values, including any object or the string
>   "false", create an object with an initial value of true.
>
> Do not confuse the primitive Boolean values true and false with the
>   true and false values of the Boolean object.

[Source, as well as the answer to your questions](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Boolean)

Answer (score 0):

```
a = new Boolean()
```

> The [[PrimitiveValue]] internal property of the newly constructed Boolean object is set to ToBoolean(value). [See here](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.6.2.1)

This means a is a `Boolean` object with the primitive value of `false` (`ToBoolean(undefined)`).

---

```
a == false // true
```

> If Type(x) is Boolean, return the result of the comparison ToNumber(x) == y. [See here](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.9.3)

`ToNumber(a)` will be `0` because the primitive value of `a` is `false`. `0==false`

---

```
Boolean(a) // true
```

> When Boolean is called as a function rather than as a constructor, it performs a type conversion. [See here](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.6.1)

Since `a` is an object, `Boolean(a)` will be `true`. All objects are converted to `true`.

---

```
if (a) doStuff()
```

The same thing as above, a is an object, so it is coerced to true in an if statement.